# How to create 2D slices of 3D object model in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt3d

I'm currently rendering a 3D model (Wavefront .obj format) in my Qt program. Right now, I'm rendering the model using Scene3D in QML, and I'm able to get it to display in the viewing area. What I would like to do is have a user click on the model and generate a 2D cross section of the slice that I would like to plot on a different window. I'm quite new to 3D rendering, and a lot of Qt documentation isn't very descriptive. I've been reading Qt documentation, experimenting, and searching online with no luck. How can I create 2D slices of a 3D object Model in Qt 3D, preferably in QML? What Qt libraries or classes can I use to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in Qt for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the fact that models are stored as a set of surfaces makes this hard. QT probably doesn't have a built in method for this.

Consider, for example, that a model made of faces might be *missing* a face. What now? can you interpolate across that gap consistently from different angles? What about the fact that a cross-section probably won't contain any vertices?

But, of course, it can be solved. First, just don't allow un-closed surfaces (meshes with holes). Second, for finding the vertices of your cross-section, perform an intersection between every edge in your model and the plane you're using, and if there's an intersection, there's a point there. Third, to find the edges, look at the list of vertices, and any two that are from an edge on the same polygon in the mesh should be connected by an edge in the cross section. To find which direction the edge should go, project the normal of the polygon onto the plane your using. For filling, I don't really know what to do. I guess that's whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you, we were able to figure out how to draw it using canvas and the algorithm you suggested. One question, if the model is missing is face or has holes, what can we do to attempt to fill the hole?

Comment: Wow, you got it working? Cool! To close a surface, maybe you can use an [ear-clipping](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf). It might not work though. If a single face is flipped upside-down in an otherwise perfect mesh, I don't know what could fix it.